# How to upload file and generate unique URL to display file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csv

I have working code to upload a CSV-file an view it on the same page. I want to view each file on a unique URL. So, like this:

1. User choses a CSV-file to upload
2. Submits
3. Gets redirected to a unique URL (e.g. /Index/1234, where 1234 is a unique ID - each file that get's uploaded has a unique ID so let's say the unique ID should be "filename" or something)
4. On the unique URL, the content of the file gets displayed

I also want a list on the index where every file that is uploaded get's displayed, and then the user can choose what file to view.

**View**

```
            @using Read_CSV_MVC.Models
            @model IEnumerable<CustomerModel>
            @{
                Layout = null;
            }

            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html>
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
                <title>Index</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body {
                        font-family: Arial;
                        font-size: 10pt;
                    }

                    table {
                        border: 1px solid #ccc;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        background-color: #fff;
                    }

                        table th {
                            background-color: #B8DBFD;
                            color: #333;
                            font-weight: bold;
                        }

                        table th, table td {
                            padding: 5px;
                            border: 1px solid #ccc;
                        }

                        table, table table td {
                            border: 0px solid #ccc;
                        }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <input type="file" name="postedFile" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Import" />
                }
                @if (Model.Count() > 0)
                {
                    <hr />
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Customer Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (CustomerModel customer in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@customer.CustomerId</td>
                                <td>@customer.Name</td>
                                <td>@customer.Country</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                }
            </body>
            </html>
```

**Controller**

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.Mvc;
        using System.IO;
        using Read_CSV_MVC.Models;

        namespace Read_CSV_MVC.Controllers
        {
            public class HomeController : Controller
            {
                // GET: Home
                public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    return View(new List<CustomerModel>());
                }

                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
                {
                    List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel>();
                    string filePath = string.Empty;
                    if (postedFile != null)
                    {
                        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
                        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                        }

                        filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                        string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                        //Read the contents of CSV file.
                        string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

                        //Execute a loop over the rows.
                        foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                            {
                                customers.Add(new CustomerModel
                                {
                                    CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[0]),
                                    Name = row.Split(',')[1],
                                    Country = row.Split(',')[2]
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return View(customers);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Model**

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;

        namespace Read_CSV_MVC.Models
        {
            public class CustomerModel
            {
                ///<summary>
                /// Gets or sets CustomerId.
                ///</summary>
                public int CustomerId { get; set; }

                ///<summary>
                /// Gets or sets Name.
                ///</summary>
                public string Name { get; set; }

                ///<summary>
                /// Gets or sets Country.
                ///</summary>
                public string Country { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to save the csv files, instead of saving whats in them? You already have an algorithm to read your csv files and pass it to a model. Why not write it to a persistent store like an (in-memory) database. This saves you the hassle of finding and re-reading them everytime a user wants to access data

Comment: I am going to set up this application within the Azure environment, so that I can store the content of the files within a Data lake storage or something like that. Anyways, this is not that important right now. The main purpose of this application is to view the content of each file on unique URLs within the application, after the file is uploaded.

Comment: You still need to persist the filename/ path with some sort if Id or key in memory. So you can map the key to the filepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Controller need to change

```
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {

        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
        var Files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel>();          
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) && Files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(id)) !=null)            {
            string filePath = Files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(id));
            string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            //Execute a loop over the rows.
            foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                {
                    customers.Add(new CustomerModel
                    {
                        CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[0]),
                        Name = row.Split(',')[1],
                        Country = row.Split(',')[2]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        ViewBag.files = Files.Select(x => x.Remove(x.LastIndexOf("."), x.Length - x.LastIndexOf(".")).Replace(path, "")).ToArray();
        return View(customers);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel>();
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            filePath = Path.Combine(path, postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            //Execute a loop over the rows.
            foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                {
                    customers.Add(new CustomerModel
                    {
                        CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[0]),
                        Name = row.Split(',')[1],
                        Country = row.Split(',')[2]
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        var Files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        ViewBag.files = Files.Select(x => x.Remove(x.LastIndexOf("."), x.Length - x.LastIndexOf(".")).Replace(path, "")).ToArray();
        return View(customers);
    }
```

and in view add this div inside body tag.

```
 <div>
    @if (ViewBag.files !=null)
    {
        foreach (var item in (string[])ViewBag.files)
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(item, "index", new { id = item })                <br />
        }
    }
</div>
```

it will works

Comment: It works now, thank you! I have two questions: 
1. how can I change the URL to be the name of the file that is uploaded?
2. I have another form on the same page which now doesnt work. It throws an exception when I submit the other form. How can I fix this?

Comment: I also noticed the filename changed in the Uploads dir. How can I prevent this from happening and keep the original name, both in the directory and in the link? @saneesh-kunjunni

Comment: ok in this case you need to change some code in this i will updated it in answer

Comment: Now i had made changes for keep file same name and even if the any other form is there in same page it will not get any error

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: How can I redirect user to the link with the filename after the file is submitted? I tried putting @Html.ActionLink(item, "Index", new { id = item }) in the form action, and putting the foreach loop around the form, but no luck.

Comment: add this code "return RedirectToAction("index", new { id = postedFile.FileName.Replace( Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName),"") }); "  before this braise close  }
        var Files = Directory.GetFiles(path);